# Stopping times, open sets and Brownian Motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stopping-times

Let $B_t$ be a brownian motion started at 0. I am trying to prove that $\tau$, defined as:
$$
\tau = \inf\{t > 0 \mbox{ }|\mbox{ } \left|B_t\right| \geq \frac{1}{1+t}  \}
$$
is a stopping time with respect to the filtration $(\mathscr{F}_{t}^B)_{t\geq 0}$.

I have some confusion concerning what if exactly measurable and what is not. I have done the following:
$$
{\{\tau \leq t\}} = \bigcup_{s\in[0,t]\cap\mathbb Q } \{\left|B_s\right| \geq \frac{1}{1+s}\} = \bigcup_{s\in[0,t]\cap\mathbb Q } \left(\Omega\setminus\{\left|B_s\right| < \frac{1}{1+s}\}\right)
$$

I can conclude by saying that $\{\left|B_s\right| < \frac{1}{1+s}\} \subseteq\mathscr{F}_{\left(\frac{1}{1+s}\right)} \subseteq \mathscr{F}_t$, **but** because I have "changed" the problem to $\Omega \setminus \{\left|B_s\right| < \frac{1}{1+s}\}$... haven't I modified the problem to the case a hitting time to an **open set**?

P.S: I know the answer is that I have not changed anything at all, I just want to make sure why.

Comment: a $\sigma$-algebra is closed by some operations, including complementation and countable union. So if $A_s$ is measurable, so is $\Omega - A_s$ and hence $\bigcup_{s \in \mathbb{Q}} (\Omega - A_s)$. In other words, hitting a closed set or an open set doesn't make any difference about being measurable, actually the Borelian algebra contains both closed set and open set. You could as well have said from the beginning that $\{ |B_s| \geq \frac{1}{1+s}\}$ is measurable because closed. By the way, I think this set is in $\mathcal{F}_s$, not $\mathcal{F}_{(\frac{1}{1+s})}$ as you wrote

Comment: You haven't changed the problem to *hitting time* of an open set.  If anything you've changed it to *first exit time* from an open set (though it's a little weird to say that, since the open set in question is time dependent).  But your approach is slightly wrong: consider the possibility that $B_s$ just touches the level $\frac{1}{1+s}$ for an instant and then goes back down, but the instant at which it touches is irrational.

Comment: @NateEldredge thanks for your answer. You are now making me think about $B_s$ touching level $\frac{1}{1+s}$ at an instant which is irrational. Why would that be a problem? Is there another standard approach to prove in this particular case that $\tau$ is a stopping time?

Comment: The event that $B_s$ touches level $\frac{1}{1+s}$ at an irrational time before $t$ is contained in the event $\{\tau \le t\}$ but not in your union over $[0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$, so the equality you wrote is false.

Comment: l.7: unless I'm mistaken, the event $|B_s|<\frac{1}{1+s}$ is in $F_s$ and not what you wrote directly.